# same site issue for .net apps hosted on Azure IAAS with Azure AD integration

Tags: asp.net, azure, google-chrome, azure-active-directory, samesite

We have ASP.NET Webforms as well as ASP.NET MVC apps with Azure AD Integration which is hosted on Azure IAAS environment. Due to recent Chrome security release version > 80 and above, most of the apps started breaking. Please find below framework version

1. All the APPS were running on 4.5.2 and also dependent NuGet package

   To fix the issue we explored the below option. As we have multiple options we need expert inputs on what option is best for APPS with Azure AD Integration.
2. To set IIS rewrite rule under the `system.webServer` tag. It is working without any code changes and framework upgrade

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <preConditions>
      <!-- Checks User Agent to identify browsers incompatible with SameSite=None -->
      <preCondition name="IncompatibleWithSameSiteNone" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(CPU iPhone OS 12)|(iPad; CPU OS 12)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(Chrome/5)|(Chrome/6)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="( OS X 10_14).*(Version/).*((Safari)|(KHTML, like Gecko)$)" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
    <!-- Adds or changes SameSite to None for the session cookie -->
    <!-- Note that secure header is also required by Chrome and should not be added here -->
    <rule name="SessionCookieAddNoneHeader">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*)(SameSite=.*)?"  />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}; SameSite=None; Secure" />
    </rule>
    <!-- Removes SameSite=None header from all cookies, for most incompatible browsers -->
    <rule name="CookieRemoveSameSiteNone" preCondition="IncompatibleWithSameSiteNone">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*)(SameSite=.*)?"  />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

3. The other option we tried to update the Framework version to 4.7.2 and respective nuget packages. It required code changes at OpenIDconnect. We tried to implement the same based on documentation provided by Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-handle-samesite-cookie-changes-chrome-browser?tabs=dotnet

4. The third was to try to downgrade the framework version to 4.5.0 and respective NuGet packages. This option is also working fine.

Comment: You may need to provide more information here on what you mean by "breaking". What are the details of the cookies being sent, i.e. contents of `Set-Cookie` header. What errors are you seeing? What domains are involved? You can find instructions on debugging on https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: we have our intranet domain and for azure AD has login.microsoft.com. it will cause the same site issue. As i mentioned in my questions we have tried 3 different option to fix the same. Just wanted to know what option is best .

Comment: When we faced the same situation in our .NET Core, Angular, Identity Server app, as suggested we just hosted the site on https (even for development) and installed the latest version of the .NET Core SDK. This solved the issue for us.